# Calculating cubic volume between 2 coordinates

Tags: java, c, math, cubic

I need a little bit of help.
I basically want to calculate the block count between two coordinates in the world, but I'm not too good at math as you can see, so If you have a solution please write it to me.
This is important so please write it, I'd appreciate it!

```
int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, z2 = 0;
x2 = x // pos x in the coord
y2 = y // pos y in the coord
z2 = z // pos z in the coord
x1 = x;
y1 = y;
z1 = z;
int a = Math.abs(Math.abs(x1)-(Math.abs(x2)));
int b = Math.abs(Math.abs(y1)-(Math.abs(y2)));
int c = Math.abs(Math.abs(z1)-(Math.abs(z2)));
if(x2 != 0)
int volume = a*b*c;
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What do you expect the answer to be? (In the code you posted, all your coordinates are zero, so the answer should be zero. Perhaps show us something non-trivial that demonstrates the problem you're having.)

Comment: This not a volume calculation.  You've gone from a vector between two points and popped it into a volume calculation of some kind.  This isn't right.

Comment: Is the vector one side of the cube or a line between opposing corners?

Comment: Google 'cartesian distance between two points'. If it's a 'diagonal' divide it by root 2.  Cube it.  There are roots and powers, so you should be able to algebraicly simplify the overall equation.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect distance for `a,b,c`.

```
// int a = Math.abs(Math.abs(x1)-(Math.abs(x2)));
int a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
```

Of course, as pointed out by @Ted Hopp, code need some interesting values other than 0 to do much.

```
int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, z2 = 0;
```